# Strange titles (and bookmarks) in chromium in xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, chromium, titlebar, bookmarks

Chromium browser in xubuntu doesn't show Persian titles.

For example this site: www.farsnews.com

Screenshot (just title): 
[image]

How can I fix that?

I noticed it happens in bookmarks too.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I installed Google Chrome and have the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
dpkg -l | grep chromium-browser-l10n
```

If you have no output from this command, you need to install the language package for chromium:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser-l10n
```

Restart chromium to apply the changes.

Comment: I already have it.